# Extract shortest matching string regex

Tags: r, regex

## Minimal Reprex

Suppose I have the string `as1das2das3D`. I want to extract everything from the letter `a` to the letter `D`. There are three different substrings that match this - I want the shortest / right-most match, i.e. `as3D`.

One solution I know to make this work is `stringr::str_extract("as1das2das3D", "a[^a]+D")`

## Real Example

Unfortunately, I can't get this to work on my real data. In my real data I have string with (potentially) two URLs and I'm trying to extract the one that's immediately followed by `rel=\"next\"`. So, in the below example string, I'd like to extract the URL `https://abc.myshopify.com/ZifQ`.

```
foo <- "<https://abc.myshopify.com/YifQ>; rel=\"previous\", <https://abc.myshopify.com/ZifQ>; rel=\"next\""

# what I've tried
stringr::str_extract(foo, '(?<=\\<)https://.*(?=\\>; rel\\="next)')          # wrong output
stringr::str_extract(foo, '(?<=\\<)https://(?!https)+(?=\\>; rel\\="next)')  # error
```

Comment: have you tried `https:[^;]+(?=;\s+rel=\W+next)`?

Comment: `https(?:(?!https).)+(?=>; rel=\"next)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
stringr::str_extract(foo,"https:[^;]+(?=>; rel=\"next)")
[1] "https://abc.myshopify.com/ZifQ"
```

or even

```
stringr::str_extract(foo,"https(?:(?!https).)+(?=>; rel=\"next)")
[1] "https://abc.myshopify.com/ZifQ"
```

Answer (score 0):

Would this be an option?

Splitting string on `;` or `,` comparing it with target string and take url from its previous index.

```
urls <- strsplit(foo, ";\\s+|,\\s+")[[1]]
urls[which(urls == "rel=\"next\"") - 1]
#[1] "<https://abc.myshopify.com/ZifQ>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here may be an option.

```
gsub(".+\\, <(.+)>; rel=\"next\"", "\\1", foo, perl = T)
#[1] "https://abc.myshopify.com/ZifQ"
```